# Identify if the navigation is a pop or a push in a child view controller

Tags: ios

Unfortunately, isMovingToParentViewController is not working in a child view controller. It always returns NO in viewWillDisappear in my case.

**Reproduce steps:**

1. Create a custom container view controller.
2. Add a child view controller in it.
3. Embed the container in a `UINavigationController`
4. Write testing code in `viewWillDisappear:` of the child view controller.
5. Push the container and then back, verify that in the `viewWillDisappear:` method, isMovingToParentViewController is always `NO`.

**Question**

Is there any way to know the navigation direction discard if it's a child view controller or not?

Or is there any point that I need to notice when implementing my container view controller?

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs for `isMovingFromParentViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willMoveToParentViewController:):

> This method returns `YES` only when called from inside the
>   `viewWillDisappear:` and `viewDidDisappear:` methods.

And [`isMovingToParentViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didMoveToParentViewController:):

> This method returns `YES` only when called from inside the
>   `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` methods.

So if it's suitable to use this information here, move your code to these view appearance methods.

If not, you will have to implement some kind of logic yourself. This could involve the container controller passing a `Bool` to the child view controllers for each transition, or having a delegate method on the container controller that returns the required information.

Answer (score 1):

### Updated Answer

The basis of the original answer (below) still stands. We'll use `isMovingToParentViewController` and `isMovingFromParentViewController` in the **container** view controller to determine the push/pop, and in turn notify the **embedded** (or child) view controller.

To make it as flexible as possible (there could be many `UIViewController` subclasses that are embedded) I have defined an `EmbeddableViewController` category.

```
@protocol EmbeddableViewController <NSObject>

- (void)embeddable_isBeingPushedOntoNavigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController;

- (void)embeddable_isBeingPoppedOffNavigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController;

@end
```

Each embedded/child view controller would need to conform to this protocol:

```
@interface EmbeddedViewController : UIViewController <EmbeddableViewController>

@end

@implementation EmbeddedViewController

- (void)embeddable_isBeingPushedOntoNavigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController {
    // do whatever
}

- (void)embeddable_isBeingPoppedOffNavigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController {
    // do whatever
}

@end
```

The **container** view controller would need to get a reference to the embedded view controller in the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method, detect the push/pop navigation and notify the embedded view controller:

```
@interface OuterViewController ()
// Keep a reference to the embedded controller
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController<EmbeddableViewController>* embeddedViewController;

@end

@implementation OuterViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self notifyEmbeddedViewControllerOfNavigation];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self notifyEmbeddedViewControllerOfNavigation];
}

- (void)notifyEmbeddedViewControllerOfNavigation {

    if ([self isMovingToParentViewController]) {
        [self.embeddedViewController embeddable_isBeingPushedOntoNavigationController:self.navigationController];
    } else if ([self isMovingFromParentViewController]) {
        [self.embeddedViewController embeddable_isBeingPoppedOffNavigationController:self.navigationController];
    }

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    [super prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];

    // Assuming the storyboard has set the embed segue's identifier to "Embedded"
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Embedded"]) {
        self.embeddedViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}

@end
```

Console output from [updated sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hm8sps69ssiottq/NavigationController-31959245-update.zip?dl=0):

```
2015-08-12 09:51:41.900 stack2[2263:569042] OuterViewController Is being pushed
2015-08-12 09:51:41.901 stack2[2263:569042] EmbeddedViewController -[EmbeddedViewController embeddable_isBeingPushedOntoNavigationController:]
2015-08-12 09:51:42.777 stack2[2263:569042] OuterViewController Is being pushed
2015-08-12 09:51:42.778 stack2[2263:569042] EmbeddedViewController -[EmbeddedViewController embeddable_isBeingPushedOntoNavigationController:]
2015-08-12 09:51:44.037 stack2[2263:569042] OuterViewController Is being pushed
2015-08-12 09:51:44.037 stack2[2263:569042] EmbeddedViewController -[EmbeddedViewController embeddable_isBeingPushedOntoNavigationController:]
2015-08-12 09:51:44.777 stack2[2263:569042] OuterViewController Is being popped
2015-08-12 09:51:44.777 stack2[2263:569042] EmbeddedViewController -[EmbeddedViewController embeddable_isBeingPoppedOffNavigationController:]
2015-08-12 09:51:45.409 stack2[2263:569042] OuterViewController Is being popped
2015-08-12 09:51:45.410 stack2[2263:569042] EmbeddedViewController -[EmbeddedViewController embeddable_isBeingPoppedOffNavigationController:]
2015-08-12 09:51:46.174 stack2[2263:569042] OuterViewController Is being popped
2015-08-12 09:51:46.174 stack2[2263:569042] EmbeddedViewController -[EmbeddedViewController embeddable_isBeingPoppedOffNavigationController:]
```

---

### Original Answer

From the docs for [`isMovingToParentViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/isMovingToParentViewController):

> This method returns YES only when called from inside the
>   viewWillAppear: and viewDidAppear: methods.

And [`isMovingFromParentViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/isMovingFromParentViewController):

> This method returns YES only when called from inside the
>   viewWillDisappear: and viewDidDisappear: methods.

Armed with this knowledge the child view controller can determine whether the navigation is a push or a pop...

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self checkNavigationDirection];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self checkNavigationDirection];
}

- (void)checkNavigationDirection {
    if ([self isMovingToParentViewController]) {
        NSLog(@"%p Is being pushed", self);
    }
    else if ([self isMovingFromParentViewController]) {
        NSLog(@"%p Is being popped", self);
    }
}
```

Results in the (sample) console output after pushing 3 view controllers, followed by popping 3 view controllers:

```
2015-08-12 09:10:56.296 stack2[1487:358827] 0x7fff09e0bba0 Is being pushed
2015-08-12 09:10:57.420 stack2[1487:358827] 0x7fff09f6b980 Is being pushed
2015-08-12 09:10:58.365 stack2[1487:358827] 0x7fff09c2f800 Is being pushed
2015-08-12 09:10:59.167 stack2[1487:358827] 0x7fff09c2f800 Is being popped
2015-08-12 09:10:59.782 stack2[1487:358827] 0x7fff09f6b980 Is being popped
2015-08-12 09:11:00.311 stack2[1487:358827] 0x7fff09e0bba0 Is being popped
```

Feel free to download the [sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5sna9bib7oyksaf/NavigationController-31959245.zip?dl=0).

Comment: Ok the similarity in the first parts of our answers is a little creepy.

Comment: As is the fact I was thinking just that! Haha

Comment: Are your testing view controller a **child** view controller?

Comment: Yes the code listed above is in a `UIViewController` subclass that is embedded within a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: I have added a link to a sample project in my answer.

Comment: Ah...I need to update my question then. First you need to have a custom container VC, and add a child VC. Write the testing code in the child VC. Embed the container VC in a UINavigationController, and nav the container VC to see what happens.

Comment: I understand now, it's a bit more complicated but not excessively so. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Three viewController A--push-->B--push-->C
2. Add a BOOL var in B, eg: _isPush
3. In viewDidLoad of B, set _isPush = YES; viewWillDisappear of B: set _isPush = NO;

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       _isPush = YES;
   }

   - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
       [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
        _isPush = NO;
   }
   ```
4. In viewWillAppear of B:

   ```
   - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
       [super viewWillAppear:animated];
       if (_isPush) {
            do something...
       } else {
            other...
       }
   }
   ```

   `